# babel-plugin-rewire with mocha and react not working

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, babeljs, stub

I have an interesting situation:

I am using `babel-plugin-rewire` in my mocha tests like so:

```
// given
MySystemUnderTest.__Rewire__("ChildComponent", ({ prop }) => {
      return <div>{prop}</div>;
});

const mockProps = {
    prop: "hello, world!"
};

// when
const { getByText } = render(<MySystemUnderTest {...mockProps} />);

// then
await waitForElement(() => getByText("hello, world!"));

MySystemUnderTest.__ResetDependency__("ChildComponent");
```

I have been using WebStorm's Mocha test runner with the following config:
`--require @babel/polyfill --require @babel/register --require mocha-setup.js --require ignore-styles --timeout 10000`
to run individual tests and it works like a charm.

However, as soon as I run the entire test suite using a glob with this command specified in my package.json:

```
"mocha": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha --require @babel/polyfill --require @babel/register --require mocha-setup.js --require ignore-styles --timeout 10000 './src/**/*.test.js'",
```

The tests with rewire just fail. There are no warnings but it looks like the stubbing of the child components just never happens and so it renders the entire tree.

My babel setup is defined in the package.json also:

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node",
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      "react-hot-loader/babel",
      "rewire"
    ]
  }
```

- react v 16.11.0
- @babel/core v 7.7.2
- babel-plugin-rewire 1.2.0

Using create react app with react-scripts v 3.2.0

Comment: Do you undo the mocking between tests? `MySystemUnderTest.__ResetDependency__("ChildComponent");` https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-rewire Shows many example of how to write tests.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Yes I do. That is not the issue, the issue is that the component is never mocked when I run multiple test files.

Comment: You'll need to include some more complete examples of your tests then.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Please see updated question. Are you able to provide an answer now?